# vim: setting different status line for split windows

Tags: vim

When I open 2 files with horizontal split, each windows has its own status line.

e.g. with command

```
vim -o a.txt b.txt
```

I will get status line as "a.txt" for first window, and "b.txt" for second window.

I need to invoke vim from command line, and I need to put a custom status line, and I want different status line for each window.

With

```
vim -o -c "set statusline=hello" a.txt b.txt
```

I am getting "hello" as status for both windows.

What should I do to get "hello" as status line for first window, and "world" for second window; when invoking vim from command line?

This command isn't working:

```
vim -o -c "set statusline=hello" a.txt -c "set statusline=world" b.txt
```

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `setlocal` command:

```
vim -o a.txt b.txt -c "setl stl=hello | wincmd j | setl stl=world"
```

---

Type `:help 'stl'`

```
'statusline' 'stl'      string  (default empty)
                        global or local to window |global-local|
```

We can see that: `stl` is a `global or local to window` option.
So, `:setl stl=hello` will set a status-line which is local to current window.